# How to display the sum of time from database using php?

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I use this as my timer and save this data to database

```
<input type="text" class="timer timer-count timer-box" id="tst" name="tst" value="0:0" readonly="readonly"/>
        <br /><br />
        <script>
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        var timer={

         init:function(id){
           this[id]={
           obj:document.getElementById(id)
          }
         },

         start:function(id){
          var obj=this[id];
          obj.srt=new Date();
          clearTimeout(obj.to);
          this.tick(id)
         },

         stop:function(id){
          clearTimeout(this[id].to);
         },

         tick:function(id){
          this.stop(id);
          var obj=this[id],sec=(new Date()-obj.srt)/1000,min=Math.floor(sec/60),sec=sec%60;
          obj.obj.value=min +':'+parseInt(sec>1?sec:'0'+sec);
          obj.to=setTimeout(function(){ timer.tick(id); },1000);
         }

        }

        timer.init('tst');
        /*]]>*/

        </script>
```

I want to display the sum of all the timer from database. I don't know how to code it.

```
<table class="table table-bordered sans-pro-light">

          <thead>
          <tr>
          <th class="text-center text-top">TOTAL TIME</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><?php /* DISPLAY TOTAL SUM OF TIME HERE */ ?></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>

          </table>
```

I use this code to submit my data to database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hsncs_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO hsncs_tbl (id, time_duration)
VALUES
('', '$_POST[tst]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

I wanted to use this to my system and I need to finish it right away. Please help me finish my project. I appreciate your big help. Thank you :)

Comment: when I say "project" - it doesn't mean I'm still at school. duh?

Comment: Sorry for that. Here's how I submit the data. Please check the code again. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use SQL ..SQL sample is :

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`total_time`))) FROM `table` WHERE . .
```

May be its help you

Comment: what's next on where?